# /proc/kcore too big

Tags: partitioning, proc

After experiencing a DDoS attack, somehow `/proc/kcore` is very huge, I use a small PHP class to check the current disk space, and how many has been used.

It shows the following:

```
Total Disk Space: 39.2 GB
Used Disk Space: 98 GB
Free Disk Space: 811.6 MB
```

My question: Is it safe to delete the `/proc/kcore` file? Or is there a solution on getting it to an normal size.

The filesize of `/proc/kcore` is 140.737.486.266.368 bytes

I have hosted my server at DigitalOcean.

Comment: Which OS and version are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing in /proc is "real", it's a virtual filesystem that allows you to see inside the kernel. When you read or write from any of these files you're talking directly with the kernel, not actually creating files on disk. From `man proc`:

> /proc/kcore
>
> This file represents the  physical  memory  of  the  system  and  is  stored  in  the  ELF  core  file  format.   With  this  pseudo-file,  and  an  unstripped  kernel
>   (/usr/src/linux/vmlinux) binary, GDB can be used to examine the current state of any kernel data structures.
>
> The total length of the file is the size of physical memory (RAM) plus 4KB.

I'm not sure how true the last line is; on my laptop /proc/kcore shows up as 128TB! It's more likely the size of the address space used by the kernel or something.

Regardless, if you need more disk space you need to look at the real filesystems. Take a look at the output of `df -h` to see where your space is running low. You can also then use the `du` command to see in more detail where space is really being used.

Interestingly, if you run `du -h /proc/kcore` you'll see it says `0`. :)